# "Variable Definition" vs "Variable Assignment" in Python

Tags: python, variables

I understand that in Python you don't need to "declare" variables because it is dynamic. However I was wondering what was the correct way of saying it:

1. "Assign a variable"
2. "Define a variable"

This is just out of curiosity, but it also would be nice to understand it for documentation purposes.

Are they the same? If they are interchangeable, What is the preferred way?

Comment: In Python, the correct way is really to say _'Bind a value to a name'_.

Comment: *Bind a value to name*.

Comment: Please don't answer questions in comments.

Comment: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: These are not complete answers, nor is the question necessarily answerable in its current form, within the constraints of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just to confuse things further, you *can* do assignments in Python, by assigning to a slice.

Comment: Thanks to all. To summarize, you will all prefer (and better understand) comments saying something like _"# Bind a list containing tuples with data from..."_ instead of _"# Define a list containing tuples with data from..."_ Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you bind a "name" to an object.

From https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html:

> "Names refer to objects. Names are introduced by name binding
>   operations. Each occurrence of a name in the program text refers to
>   the binding of that name established in the innermost function block
>   containing the use."

Also, you may wish to see visualization like [this](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+=+1%0Ab+=+a%0Aa+=+2%0A%0Ac+=+%5B1,+2,+3%5D%0Ad+=+%5B%5B1,2%5D,+%5B2,3%5D%5D&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=5), to make things more clear.